# Composer required for website; no SSH access

Tags: php, api, composer-php

I'm trying to set-up Amazon API for my website. Basically something like http://apaiio.dev.pixel-web.org/ with its source files from https://github.com/Exeu/apai-io
From the documentation, I need to install composer, however I have no SSH connection to the server. Is there any other way to install this? I basically just need product price, description, image and link.

Comment: No, there is no way to install the composer dependency manager without SSH access to the server.

Comment: All Composer will do, however, is take the files from GitHub automatically as they're updated, so if you don't have SSH access, then just grab the files straight from GitHub and upload them manually.

Comment: @OraBrush: Grabbing them manually won't create the autoloader.

Answer (score 1):

How do you install your website on the server? FTP/SFTP/SCP/FTPS access? Then you should install Composer on the machine that uploads it and execute Composer there, and upload after it has done it's job.

Comment: I didn't think of that. Nice!